# How to set up navigation with fading (sprite) background image

Tags: jquery, css, navigation, hover, fade

I have designed a sprite that looks like this:

[image]

The idea is to have the upper portion of the image fade in on hover (in a navigation system).  I have everything working except for the text for the navigation items.  As you can see on [this page](http://www.soterianetwork.org.uk/test/), the text for the navigation fades in and out with the background image, as it is contained within the span that is faded.  I wonder if someone could help me get my head round how I can keep the text always showing.

Here is the html:

```
<ul class="navigation">
    <li><a href=""><span>home</span></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><span>contact</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

And the CSS:

```
body, ul,li { 
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

ul {
    list-style:none;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    line-height: 30px;
}

ul a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.navigation li { 
    background: url(nav.png) no-repeat 0 -30px;
    width: 223px;
    height: 30px;
}

.navigation li span {
    background: url(nav.png) no-repeat 0 0px;
    width: 223px;
    height: 30px;
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
```

and the script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".navigation li a").hover(function () {
        $(this).children("span").stop().animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, 300);
    }, function () {
        $(this).children("span").animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, 400);
    });
});
```

Thanks,

Nick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick. Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/zDwP9/2/

**HTML:** (Moved `span` outside of `a` tag)

```
<ul class="navigation">
    <li><a href="">home</a><span></span></li>
    <li><a href="">contact</a><span></span></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS Changes:** (Widened `li`, floated `a` left and `span` right, adjusted width and background position of `span`)

```
ul a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
    float:left;
    width: 204px;
}

.navigation li span {
    background: url(nav.png) no-repeat -204px 0;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    float:right;
}
```

**jQuery/JavaScript:** (Changed selector from `li a` to `li`)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".navigation li").hover(function () {
        $(this).children("span").stop().animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, 300);
    }, function () {
        $(this).children("span").animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, 400);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Dont put the background image on the span.

HTML

```
<ul class="navigation">
    <li><a href=""><div class="background"></div><span>home</span></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><div class="background"></div><span>contact</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.navigation li { 
    position: relative;
    background: url(nav.png) no-repeat 0 -30px;
    width: 223px;
    height: 30px;
}

.navigation li span {
    width: 223px;
    height: 30px;
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}

.navigation li .background {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background: url(nav.png) no-repeat 0 0px;
    width: 223px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".navigation li a").hover(function () {
        $(this).children(".background").stop().animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, 300);
    }, function () {
        $(this).children(".background").animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, 400);
    });
});
```